# module.export undefind on object destruct node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Here is my global.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;
```

and i am require like

`const  {globals}  = require('core').globals;` but this returns undefined in `console.log(globals)`

But this

`const  globals  = require('core').globals;`

returns the proper object

So why I am getting undefined in the first case??

**Note**

`core` is my local module its contains the global.js file

Comment: @Jonas W has the answer. How you are requiring is called destructuring. You can read about it [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const {globals} = require('core').globals;
```

Is equal to

```
 const globals = require('core').globals.globals;
```

And that probably does not exist. I guess you wanted to do:

```
 const {globals} = require('core');
```